# C++11 Pointer (void**)&data

Tags: c++11, pointers

I'm still learning C++, and I'm doing some API work, but I'm, having trouble parsing this pointer arrangement.

```
void* data;
res = npt.receive(0x1007, params, 1, response, (void**)&data, size);
uint32_t* op = (uint32_t*)data;
uint32_t num = *op;
op++;
```

Can anyone explain what is going on with that void pointer? I see it being defined, it does something in the res line(maybe initialized?), then it's copied to an uint32 pointer, and dereferenced in num. Can anyone help me parse the (void**)&data declaration?

Comment: What exactly didn't you understand? Do you know what a `void *` is?

Comment: Sure, a void pointer is a pointer that can contain the address of any object. A void ** is the address of a pointer that contains the address of any object. void pointers have limitations, like the inability to dereference. What I don't understand is (void**)&data. Since data is defined above as a void pointer and &data is a reference to the address of data, what does (void**) do? Can a reference be assigned a void** type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly: What is npt?

Secondly: Guessing what npt could be some explanation:

```
// Declare a pointer to void named data
void* data;
// npt.receive takes as 5th parameter a pointer to pointer to void,
// which is why you provide the address of the void* using &data. 
// The void ** appears to be unnecessary unless the data type of the
// param is not void **
// What is "npt"?
res = npt.receive(0x1007, params, 1, response, (void**)&data, size);
// ~.receive initialized data with contents.
// Now make the uint32_t data usable by casting void * to uint32_t*
uint32_t* op = (uint32_t*)data;
// Use the data by dereferencing it.
uint32_t num = *op;
// Pointer arithmetic: Move the pointer by sizeof(uint32_t).
// Did receive fill in an array?
op++;
```

### Update

Signature of receive is:

```
<whatever return type> receive(uint16_t code, uint32_t* params, uint8_t nparam, Container& response, void** data, uint32_t& size)
```

So the data parameter is of type void** already so the explicit type cast to void** using (void**) is not necessary.

Considering the usage, the received data appears to be an array of uint32_t values IN THIS CASE!

Void as a type means `no type` and no type information regarding size and alignment is available, but is mandatory for lexical and syntactical consistency.

In conjunction with the *, it can be used as a pointer to data of unknown type and must be explicitly cast to another type (adds type information) before any use.

You usually have a void* or void** in an API, if you dont know the specific data type or only received plain byte data.

To understand this please read up `C type erasure using void*`

Please read up as basics before:

1. Dynamically allocated C arrays.
2. Pointers and Pointer Arithmetics.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot tell you what it does specifically, but it's designed to talk to a hardware device, send an op code, and some parameters, and receiving a response code and some data

Comment: I guess I don't understand the syntax (void**)&data.  Is this forcing a type declaration like int foo; but instead it's (void**) as a type declaration for the address of &data? Are the parentheses required here? Couldn't I just put &data, since it's the address of a void pointer?

Comment: If we had the signature of receive I could explain the specific meaning an necessity for the parentheses

Comment: `receive(uint16_t code, uint32_t* params, uint8_t nparam, Container& response, void
 ** data, uint32_t& size)`

It also says receive() should perform receiving transaction with data phase.\n
 * Please allocate buffer needed to receive from device in this method

The english is a little bit tough to parse, it's foreign

Comment: You got it! I believe plain byte data is received from the hardware device, and thank you for the additional reading. C/C++ seems quite complex, and I'm always looking to learn more.

Answer (score 2):

Pay attention when you use the void pointer:

> The void type of pointer is a special type of pointer. In C++, void represents the absence of type. Therefore, void pointers are pointers that point to a value that has no type (and thus also an undetermined length and undetermined dereferencing properties).
>   This gives void pointers a great flexibility, by being able to point to any data type, from an integer value or a float to a string of characters. In exchange, they have a great limitation: the data pointed to by them cannot be directly dereferenced (which is logical, since we have no type to dereference to), and for that reason, any address in a void pointer needs to be transformed into some other pointer type that points to a concrete data type before being dereferenced.

From [C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/)

Comment: Good to know, I did find that section in C++ Primer 11, I'm pretty sure that's why it's cast to a uint_32_t afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

From the code, ntp.receive tells you whether it receives anything successfully in the return code but it also needs to give you *what* it receives. It has a pointer that it wants to pass back, so you have to tell it *where* that pointer is so that it can fill it, hence (void **), a pointer to a pointer, being the address of your pointer, &data.

When you have received it, you know as the developer that what it points to is actually a uint_32 value so you copy the void pointer into one that points to a uint_32. In fact, this step is unnecessary since you could have cast the uint_32 pointer to void** in the above call but we'll let that slide.

Now that you have told the compiler that the pointer points to a 32 bit number, you can take the number on the other end of that pointer (*op) and store it in a local variable. Again, unnecessary, as *op could be used anywhere num is subsequently used.

Hope this helps.